# Загрузка <script> по адресу не удалась

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-mvc, tomcat

Пытаюсь связать Angular 1.6.9 с Spring MVC
Однако при деплое на Tomcat оно не хочет подгружать script, выдавая данную ошибку:

```
Загрузка <script> по адресу «http://localhost:8080/js/index.js» не удалась.
```

Папка js-файлов в tomcat:

```
C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.28\webapps\page\WEB-INF\js
```

Имеется простая страница:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html ng-app="mainApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Spring MVC and AngularJS</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="Hello">

            <p>This ID is {{type.id}}</p>
            <p>This name is {{type.name}}</p>           
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

к нему относится данный js-файл:

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

mainApp.controller('Hello', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/page/main").
        then(function(response){
            $scope.type = response.data;
        });
});
```

Иерархия проекта:

[image: Моя иерархия]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [Java™ Servlet Specification version 3.1](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) написано:

> A special directory exists within the application hierarchy named
>   WEB-INF. This directory contains all things related to the application
>   that aren’t in the document root of the application. **The WEB-INF node**
>   **is not part of the public document tree of the application.** No file
>   contained in the WEB-INF directory may be served directly to a client
>   by the container. However, the contents of the WEB-INF directory are
>   visible to servlet code using the getResource and getResourceAsStream
>   method calls on the ServletContext, and may be exposed using the
>   RequestDispatcher calls.

Не надо в WEB-INF складывать статику.